# Existing Record Field Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, record

I'm having a weird issue with record access in some d3 code. As the screenshots show, my datapoints contain a field called "country" that has a non-null value. However, accessing this value with d.country is returning "undefined". I can access all of the other fields of the record using dot notation and the correct values are returned.

[image: web console output]

[image: code]

Comment: Please post your code as text and not screenshots !

Comment: I actually figured out what the problem was. For some reason, excel is appending an extra white space to the header and entries of the last column and I wasn't catching the issue because other features of the app that depend on header names pull them as a variable directly from the list of headers rather than using them by a specific name as I was doing.

Out of curiosity, why is text better than screenshots?

Comment: To answer your question, `Out of curiosity, why is text better than screenshots?` -- when you ask a question you should strive to provide enough information for us to re-produce your problem.  I screenshot is not helpful for this (no one is going to transcribe it).  Further, a screenshot is not searchable.  If others in the future have a similar issue, your code won't be searchable via google or stack exchange.